# Generate release notes and send via E-mail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've created a release pipeline which generates release notes, and later publishes it on the Wiki.

Only issue i am having is that the Wiki cannot be updated, but rather a new Wiki pages/sub-page needs to be created manually each time. Due to this, i was wondering if there's anyway i can send my release notes to an email address instead?

my PowerShell

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\releasenotes.md")
$data = @{content=$content;} | ConvertTo-Json;

$connectionToken= '[token]'

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$params = @{uri = '$(WikiPath)';
  Method = 'PUT';
  Headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" };
  ContentType = "application/json";
  Body = $data;
}
Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

Any guide will be appreciated, quite new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on whether you're using a on-premises agent or a hosted agent as you will require access to an SMTP server from the agent your job is running.  You can then simply use PowerShell to send your email:

Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHTML -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Priority High -Encoding UTF8

Wes

Comment: Cheers, where about in my PS would this need to be added to? also it is going to be a hosted agent.

Comment: You can add a PowerShell task and use the inline script option.  What are you using for your SMTP server?  In our scenario we use an on-prem agent to send emails so it has access to our internal SMTP server.

Comment: You can also try to use the Send Mail task if you're using an external SMTP server which requires username/password and/or SSL. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask

Comment: I tried to use the send mail task after installing it but it is just grayed out on DevOps . I dont know why

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, like the task is disabled?  I added it to a Build Definition and a Classic Release and it was enabled in both...  Did you click the Refresh in Add Tasks maybe??